# Getting data from node.js into HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, iis

I am new to node.js. Say node.js is running on

> localhost:9090//nodejs/server/messages/1

In that url.Application is running in

> localhost:8080/

I want to access the node,js result in a HTML page.

```
function get_message() {
  $.getJSON('/nodejs/server/messages/1', function (result) {
    var df = result;
    document.getElementById('txtCompanyId').value = result[0]['CompanyID'];
    document.getElementById('txtCompanyName').value = result[2]['CompanyName'];
  });
}
```

This function I am using leads to a cross-domain exception. I solved it using proxy settings in Apache. How to configure this setting in IIS? Or how to call that node.js url in Javascript while running on IIS server?

Then how to host the node.js in IIS?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use NowJS lib from https://github.com/Flotype/now, http://nowjs.com, or http://socket.io. Another thing you could try is messaging concept.